# Illegal string offset 'name' [APP\Controller\PostsController.php, line 18]

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to cakephp and php and im trying to save a file in a folder after uploading it.

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is ( 'post' )) {
        $filename = "app/webroot/img/uploads/" . $this->data ['Post'] ['Image'] ['name'];
        if ((move_uploaded_file ( $this->data ['Post'] ['Image'] ['tmp_name'], $filename ))) {
            $this->Mathang->create ();
            if ($this->Post->save ( $this->request->data )) {
                $this->Session->setFlash ( __ ( 'save images successful.' ) );
                redirect()          
                $this->redirect ( '/posts/upload' );
            }
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash ( __ ( 'not save images.' ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try `var_dump`-ing $this->data and see if the attribute 'name' is present?

Comment: @Trang Nguyen Quoc , You miss `;` at end of line: `redirect()`

Comment: You should validate the file name extension before uploading it somewhere below the web document root, otherwise one could upload a `.php` file.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
     if ($this->request->is('post') ) {          
     $filename=$this->request->data('Post.image');

    $filename = "app/webroot/img/uploads/".$_FILES[$filename]['name'];
    $tempname=$this->request->data('Post.image');
    if((move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$tempname']['tmp_name'],$filename)){

            if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('save images successful.'));
        redirect()
         $this->redirect('/posts/upload');
    }}else{
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('not save images.'));}
}
```

Comment: If providing an answer, please take the time to explain what the problem is and how to solve it, and not just dump non-parsing code.

Comment: It's have 2 error: Undefined index: images.jpg [APP\Controller\MathangsController.php, line 19] ($filename = "app/webroot/img/uploads/".$_FILES[$filename]['name'];), Undefined index: images.jpg [APP\Controller\MathangsController.php, line 21] (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$tempname]['tmp_name'],$filename))

Comment: And please, if you paste code here, at least make it format a little bit like CakePHP standard code. Right now it looks like an unreadable mess.